# Virus propagation - How long will it take for the population to become infected and how many will die?

Tags: probability

I was thinking about covid-19 and I wanted to make a problem around it! So in a village with $a$ people $b$ people had the virus and gave it to $c$ people per day. Within $d$ days of having it you can give it to other people and within $e$ days people know he has the virus so he doesn't give it to anyone else (and we know that $d<e$). It takes $f$ days to recover and you *can* get the virus again.There is a possibility of dying $\frac{1}{g}$.
How much time will it take for the whole village to get the virus and in how many days everyone will have died?
I thought something like $bc$ people the first day up to the next $d$ days so all together $bcd$ people within $d$ days.
And let's say that $$a=1000$$$$b=5$$$$c=3$$$$d=5$$$$e=10$$$$f=14$$$$g=20$$

Comment: I can't understand the timeit will take

Comment: *"Within $d$ days of having it you can give it to other people"*. Does this mean that a person is infectious for times in $(t_0,t_0+d)$ or in $(t_0+d,t_0+f)$? Note that in real life, the [period of communicability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incubation_period) can extend *beyond* the period of disease (and is typically delayed from the moment of infection).

Comment: A lot of people have worked on epidemiologic modelization. Take a look first at what they have done ; begin by the SIR model you will find for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_modelling_of_infectious_disease).